# EmberJS: how to remove records with many-to-many relationship

Tags: ember.js, many-to-many, ember-data

I stumbled across an issue when I tried to remove a record whose model is in many-to-many relationship to another.

I have Book:

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    isbn: DS.attr('string'),
    category: DS.attr('string'),
    publishDate: DS.attr('date'),
    authors: DS.hasMany('author', {inverse: 'books'})
});
```

as well as Author:

```
App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
    firstName: DS.attr('string'),
    lastName: DS.attr('string'),
    birthDate: DS.attr('date'),
    books: DS.hasMany('book', {async: true, inverse: 'authors'})
});
```

I am removing books like this:

```
actions: {
    delete: function (book) {
        var authors = book.get('authors')
        authors.forEach(function(author) {
            var books = author.get('books')
            books.forEach(function(book){
                console.log(book.toJSON());
            })
            books.removeObject(book);
            //books.save doesn't work
        })
        book.destroyRecord();
        this.transitionToRoute('books.index');
    },
```

and it correctly removes this book, with DELETE request to backing REST server, but there are no PUT requests for all those authors which had this book in their 'books' collection. When I change view to authors and go back to books one dummy book is created with id of the one I previously removed and 'authors' set to old author as well, other properties are undefined.

How do I correctly remove books so that authors are updated as well?

Comment: Do you use Ember Data beta 14? Do you get any errors in console when you see "dummy" book?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've solved it.
First issue was that on the server-side of my project I incorrectly populated data - the ids were wrong and didn't match those from their relation.

Another thing was saving incorrect object. I was trying to save only the array with books, had to save whole author instead (actually that makes sense). Working action is this:

```
console.log('Removing book: ' + book.get('id') + book.get('title'));
var authors = book.get('authors')
var id = book.get('id');
authors.forEach(function (author) {
   var books = author.get('books').removeObject(book);
   author.save();
})
book.destroyRecord();
this.transitionToRoute('books.index');
```

My only doubt was that the delete action is defined in BookController, whose model is the book I am trying to delete, so I shouldn't put the book in a parameter but use controller's model instead. And I've just found that it's easily achievable by just removing the parameter and declaring book as `this.get('model')`, that's why the final, working solution is this:

```
delete: function () {
    var book = this.get('model')
    console.log('Removing book: ' + book.get('id') + book.get('title'));
    var authors = book.get('authors')
    var id = book.get('id');
    authors.forEach(function (author) {
        var books = author.get('books').removeObject(book);
        author.save();
    })
    book.destroyRecord();
    this.transitionToRoute('books.index');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that `DS.hasMany` returns a promise, so it has to be resolved before you can use it:

```
  actions: {
    delete: function (book) {
     if (!book.get('isDeleted')) {
       book.destroyRecord()
         .catch(function(error) {
           console.log(error);
           book.rollback();
         })
         .then(function(book) {
           book.get('authors').then(function (authors) {
             authors.mapBy('books').forEach(function(books) {
                if (typeof books.then === "function") {
                  books.then(function(books) {
                    books.removeObject(book);
                  });
                } else {
                  books.removeObject(book);
                }
             });
           });
         });
      }

      this.transitionToRoute('books.index');
    }
  },
```

Comment: When trying out your solution I got this:

     `TypeError: undefined is not a function
        at controllers.js:25`

Where 25 is ` book.get('authors').then(function (authors) {`

The `delete` action is placed in BookController and I am passing a book as a parameter (which doesn't feel right, wouldn't it be better to delete the book in whose controller I am currently in? But after removing the parameter and declaring book as `this.get('model')` it still doesn't work), that's why it's not a promise.